# nodejs mp4 won't load properly

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4

I'm making a node js server, to show movies i have ripped from dvd's on my television. Of course you have to be logged in, and you can only use it on our local network. I have run into a little problem, because it works fine when i do

```
app.use("/test", express.static('movies'));
```

And then goto `http://localhost:3000/test/movie_example.mp4`, this works fine but i can't really control if the user is logged in, so i tried

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res){
    var ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    if(login.isSignedin(ip)){
        res.header("content-type", "video/mp4");
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/movies/" + req.query.movie + ".mp4");
    }
    res.send("not logged in");
});
```

And typed in `http://localhost:3000/test?movie=example_movie`, But then there comes a frame, and it takes for ever for the movie to buffer. In my eyes those two shut do the exact the same thing.

In advance, Thanks for the help

Comment: Uh... in your example, you have `movie_example.mp4`, but then in your method, you pass `example_movie` as the filename. Is that the problem?

Comment: No, i have tried. req.query.movie just returns example_movie

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. You are passing the wrong filename in the query, so the file `example_movie.mp4` doesn't exist, but `movie_example.mp4` does exist.

Comment: Oh. No, it's not those names I'm using in the app. I'm getting the names from a json file, so those shut be equal

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, using the express static service, I think if you look at a browser inspector you will find the server and browser are working together to request and send the video file in small chunks.

This allows the browser to start playback before the whole file has been downloaded.

In the second case you are simply sending the entire video file to the browser in one go, which will take much longer. Again, if you look at the browser inspector you should be able to see this.